# check if facebook post exists before making api call

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, fatal-error

I am getting a fatal php error: `"Fatal error: Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported get request. thrown in /facebook-php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php on line 1340"`, when making an api call on posts that have been deleted on facebook. i want to be able to delete the post from my database if the post has been deleted from facebook and also remove this fatal error. my api call is in a while loop to return the top posts (ranked on comments, shares and likes). i need to check for the existence of the post before returning the post and delete it from database if removed from facebook.

```
$get_content_db_info = mysqli_query($dbc , "SELECT * FROM `content`");
echo '<table id="leaugeTable"><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Post ID</th><th>Facebook ID</th><th>Score</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_content_db_info)){
    // then your for loop
    $fbApiGetPosts = $facebook->api('/'.$row["fb_id"].'_'.$row["post_id"]);
    $fbApiGetShares = $fbApiGetPosts["shares"];
    $shareCount = $fbApiGetShares["count"];
    $fbApiGetLikes = $facebook->api('/'.$row["post_id"].'/likes');
    $countLikes = $fbApiGetLikes["data"];
    $likesResult = count($countLikes);
    $fbApiGetComments = $facebook->api('/'.$row["post_id"].'/comments');
    $countComments = $fbApiGetComments["data"];
    $cc = count($countComments);
    $score = $likesResult + $shareCount * 2 + $cc * 3;
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row["first_name"].' '.$row["last_name"].'</td><td>'.$row["post_id"].'</td><td>'.$row["fb_id"].'</td><td class = "sortCol">'.$score.'</td></tr>';
}
```

this is my first facebook project and dont know how to go about this.

Comment: What fatal error are you getting?

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported get request.`

Comment: check if you are using the correct postid, check your calls in [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) too

Comment: i am the problem is the post HAS been deleted and as a result i am getting this error. no error before the post was deleted. i need a way to check if the post exists.

Comment: you can simply check for the `error` in the result. If it says `error` that means the post is deleted

Comment: Could you possibly provide an example as an answer please?

Comment: “Fatal error: __Uncaught__ GraphMethodException” – that part in bold is your mistake. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the post has been deleted from facebook, you'll see the `Fatal error: Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported get request.` error. What you can do is:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_content_db_info)){
  try {
    // your original while code
  } catch ( Exception $e ) {
    // error from facebook, post is likely to be deleted
    if ( $ex->getMessage() === 'Unsupported get request.' ) {
      // delete post from database
    }
  }
}
```

The try...catch statement will catch any errors, including `Unsupported get request.`, where you can then delete the post from the database, without affecting the rest of the flow.